# how can i install virtual box with gui on ubuntu 16.04 lts server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

How can i install virtualbox with gui on ubuntu 16.04 lts server? I already installed virtual box on ubuntu server but not any gui present.I will need virtual box because i want to install window & other os

Answer (score 1):

Because the server image of Ubuntu is a minimal installation with no desktop environment present, you have to install a GUI for Ubuntu first.

To do that on **Ubuntu 16.04 Server**, simply use the command:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

After that you should get a login prompt in your GUI session. If that does not happen, you should reboot first.

After you have your desktop environment setup, you should reinstall virtualbox:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall virtualbox
```

Or if you don't have it as a package, download the .deb again and:

```
dpkg -i <.deb_file>
```

Which will most likely fail due to missing dependancies, in which case, you just need to run:

```
sudo apt install -f
```

And that should be it.